# Refine C# Code by using Variables to Reference Form objects

Tags: c#

I have several labels on a form that I would like to be able to reset to "0".
I have it worked out by referencing each label. I have also used an array and for loop, this seems a little more efficient. Is there a way to reference each label name by using the for variable and constructing a string the evaluates to the label name without an array?

Like this:

```
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            lbls[x].Text = "0";
```

Here is my code:

```
        // Clear form labels
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label[] lbls = new Label[]
        {
            lbl1, lbl2,lbl3,lbl4,lbl5,lbl6
        };

        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
            lbls[x].Text = "0";

        //lbl1.Text = "0";
        //lbl2.Text = "0";
        //lbl3.Text = "0";
        //lbl4.Text = "0";
        //lbl5.Text = "0";
        //lbl6.Text = "0";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have other labels:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
```

will give you an `IEnumerable` of all the labels on your form, and then you can use Simons code:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList<Label>().ForEach(l => l.Text = "0");
```

Comment: I think the code need to be like this: `       this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList<Label>().ForEach(l => l.Text = "0");`

Comment: You should probably put all of the labels inside of a panel, or other container, and then get the `Controls` of that container, that way adding a label later won't have unintended side effects.

Answer (score 0):

That will be even more costly because you'll need to use Reflection to look up the object by name and set its text property to "0".

Here's a one liner for you if you want something smaller:

```
new List<Label>() { lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6 }.ForEach(x => x.Text = "0");
```

..kinda yuck though :)

Comment: That's true, however that's only because I assumed he had other labels on the form that he didn't want to do this with. If he wanted to execute this on specific labels, this is probably as clean as it gets.

Comment: unless, as servy mentioned, he assigns all of them to a single parent panel.